# Best approach for creating URLs in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Let's say we have controllers with URL mappings like `movie/{id}-{title}`, `actor/{id}-{name}`, etc. These mappings identify some objects in our app, mostly entities - we can say it's a RESTful service.

I'm looking for a solution as to where I should put methods responsible for creation of those URIs. I think that creating them in multiple JSP files and some other places (redirection, etc.) is redundant.

First, what I thought about was creating some interface with method `public URI getURI()` that classes that will be used in controllers will implement. But, in my opinion, that would involve too much into entity - I prefer entities just to represent data and contain only methods to change state.

My second idea was to create a `URIService` with overloaded methods like `URI getURI(Movie m)` and `URI getURI(Actor a)`, but there will be a problem with the choice of overloading method at compile time. For example, in EL in JSP that wouldn't work well, as the solution would be naming methods differently.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so maybe you know or use some solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How enterprisey do you want the solution to be? (I'm just half kidding)

Here's a solution: Have a service that has a method like `URI getURI(Object o)`. This method will check if the object passed belongs to a class with an annotation that specifies the URI path. Example annotation:

```
public @interface PathTemplate {String value();}
```

Example class with the annotation:

```
@PathTemplate("/movie/{title}-{id}")
public class Movie {
  private int id;private String title;
  // getters and setters too
}
```

Now, the `getURI` method will see that the parameter object's class has a `PathTemplate` annotation and will interpolate the parameters using bean introspection. Voila! Expandable and relatively decoupled URI generation.